# Have to setOnClickListener() every time layout is changed?

Tags: android

In a new app that I'm trying to create I have 3 separate layouts to switch between, and each have their own buttons on them.

Is it necessary to setOnClickListener(listener) every time that I change to that view or is there a manner of permanently adding a listener?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you intend to "switch between" these layouts?

Comment: Just with the setContentView() function :/ lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a better practice is to create 3 activities each having its own layout and then switch between them. But if you need your application to stay this way, then yes, you will need to initialize your `onClickListeners` every time you inflate new layouts. Hope this helps.

Comment: If I were to do this, then how do I go about changing which is displayed on the screen? I'm pretty new to the layout part of android as I've only really been working with Live Wallpapers.

Comment: @Jwc24678, You should visit the Dev Guide at www.developer.android.com and read articles about Activities and Intents. This will make it a bit clearer.